# Sorting Singly Linked List

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort, singly-linked-list

I have a singly linked list that needs to be sorted according some criteria. I implemented bubble sort but it does not print all the list, it prints only some of the elements. I can not use Arrays. I have to use bubble sort. I cannot use other sorting algorithms.

```
class SLLNode implements Comparable<SLLNode> {

    protected int id;
    protected int plata;
    protected SLLNode succ;

    public SLLNode(int id,int plata, SLLNode succ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.plata=plata;
        this.succ = succ;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SLLNode o) {
        return o.id - this.id;
    }

}

class SLL {

    private SLLNode first;

    public SLL() {
        // Construct an empty SLL
        this.first = null;
    }

    public void deleteList() {
        first = null;
    }

    public int length() {
        int ret;
        if (first != null) {
            SLLNode tmp = first;
            ret = 1;
            while (tmp.succ != null) {
                tmp = tmp.succ;
                ret++;
            }
            return ret;
        } else
            return 0;

    }


    public void insertFirst(int id, int plata) {
        SLLNode ins = new SLLNode(id, plata, first);
        first = ins;
    }

    public void insertLast(int id, int plata) {
        if (first != null) {
            SLLNode tmp = first;
            while (tmp.succ != null)
                tmp = tmp.succ;
            SLLNode ins = new SLLNode(id, plata, null);
            tmp.succ = ins;
        } else {
            insertFirst(id, plata);
        }
    }

    public SLLNode getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void pecati(SLL lista) {
        SLLNode p = lista.first;
        while (p != null) {
            System.out.println(p.id + " " + p.plata);
            p = p.succ;
        }
    }


}

public static void sort(SLL lista){
    SLLNode current;
    boolean check = true;
    while(check) {
        current = lista.getFirst();
        check = false;
        while(current.succ != null) {
            if(current.compareTo(current.succ) > 0) {
                SLLNode temp = current;
                current=current.succ;
                temp.succ=current.succ;
                current.succ=temp;
                check = true;
            }
            current = current.succ;
        }
    }
}

public static void deleteLower(SLL lista, int n){
    SLL newList = new SLL();
    SLLNode temp=lista.getFirst();
    while(temp!=null){
        if(temp.plata >= n){
            newList.insertLast(temp.id, temp.plata);
        }
        temp=temp.succ;
    }
    if(newList.length() == 0){
        System.out.print("no");
        return;
    }
    else{
        sort(newList);
        newList.print(newList);
    }

}
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Cannot be certain but likely you are not keeping track of head properly.

Comment: @Lawrence Aiello when i use sort function some elements disappears from list. It doesnt print the whole list.

Comment: Sorry, I have posted wrong piece of code now I corrected.

Comment: Can you show implementation of SLLNode and SLL ?

Comment: @kukis I posted implementation

Comment: You can use merge-sort as well...